# When does SwiftUI update its views?

Tags: swiftui

If you take a look at the `flagTapped` function, you will see that it modifies many `State` variables. With the use of breakpoints, I realized that `body` doesn't get updated the moment `round` gets modified, but only after the function has run.

Could someone explain to me when does SwiftUI updates its views?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var shouldShowWrongAnswer = false
    
    @State private var scoreTitle = ""
    @State private var score = 0
    @State private var round = 1
    
    // ----------------------
    
    @State private var countries = ["Estonia", "France", "Germany", "Ireland", "Italy", "Nigeria", "Poland", "Russia", "Spain", "UK", "US"]
    @State private var correctAnswer = Int.random(in: 0...2)
    
    // ----------------------
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RadialGradient(stops: [
                .init(color: Color(red: 0.1, green: 0.2, blue: 0.45), location: 0.3),
                .init(color: Color(red: 0.76, green: 0.15, blue: 0.26), location: 0.3),
            ], center: .top, startRadius: 200, endRadius: 400)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            VStack {
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Text("Guess the Flag")
                        .font(.largeTitle.weight(.bold))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                    VStack(spacing: 15) {
                        Text("Tap the flag of")
                            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                            .font(.subheadline.weight(.heavy))
                        
                        Text(countries[correctAnswer])
                            .font(.largeTitle.weight(.semibold))
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .padding(.vertical, 20)
                    .background(.regularMaterial)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
                    
                    Spacer()
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Text("Score: \(score)")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.title.bold())
                    
                    Text("Round: \(round)/8")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.caption)
                    
                    Spacer()
                }
                
                ForEach(0..<3) { number in
                    Button {
                        flagTapped(number)
                    } label: {
                        Image(countries[number])
                            .renderingMode(.original)
                            .clipShape(Capsule())
                            .shadow(radius: 5)
                    }
                }
            }.padding()
        }
        .alert(scoreTitle, isPresented: $shouldShowWrongAnswer) {
            Button("Continue", action: askQuestion)
        } message: {
            Text("Your score is \(score)")
        }
    }
    
    func flagTapped(_ number: Int) {
        if round == 8 {
            shouldShowGameEnded = true
            return
        }
        
        round += 1
        
        if number == correctAnswer {
            score += 1
            askQuestion()
        } else {
            scoreTitle = "Wrong! That’s the flag of \(countries[number])"
            shouldShowWrongAnswer = true
        }
    }
    
    func askQuestion() {
        countries.shuffle()
        correctAnswer = Int.random(in: 0...2)
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually in principle approach is not changed since UIKit: modifying state is like `setNeedsDisplay`, and `body` is just a computable property which will be called to re-render view whenever engine decided to refresh screen (most probably in next event cycle).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your device's screen has a refresh rate, which is how often the display controller reads the frame buffer and updates the actual screen pixels. Historically, the refresh rate has been 60 Hz (60 times per second), but some newer devices can refresh at up to 120 Hz. (Apple calls this higher refresh rate “ProMotion”.)

There is no point in updating the frame buffer (which means redrawing your updated views) more often that the screen will display them. If your screen refreshes at 60 Hz, then drawing your views twice within 1/60 of a second wastes resources (CPU time, GPU time, memory bandwidth, and battery power).

So the UI frameworks “coalesce” screen updates. When you do something that tells the framework that it needs to redraw a view (like change a [`DynamicProperty`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/dynamicproperty#) in SwiftUI or call [`setNeedsDisplay`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622437-setneedsdisplay#) in UIKit), the framework registers a callback with the run loop. But if the callback is already registered, it doesn't get registered a second time.

The callback is fired before the run loop would otherwise go to sleep waiting for a new event to come in. The callback unregisters itself, then gives the framework an opportunity to update view layouts and redraw them.